# R language, count the Friday in a month

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I have a data.frame named **ll** with all the dates between 2014 and 2014.
Also I have a column named **Flag_new_month** which is **1** if it's the first day of a new month and **0** otherwise.
Last I have a column named **Flag_Friday** which is **1** if it's Friday and **0** otherwise.

Here's an example:

```
Dates           Month    Weekday     Flag_new_month  Flag_Friday
2014-01-30      1        Thursday    0               0  
2014-01-31      1        Friday      0               1  
2014-02-01      2        Saturday    1               0
```

My goal is to obtain a counter of all the Friday in a month that resets to zero when a new month occurs.
I tried to do that with no success using a simple **ifelse** statement:

```
count=0
ll$Count_Friday = ifelse(ll$Flag_Friday == 1 && ll$Flag_new_month == 0, count+1,0)
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

P.S.:
First of all thanks for the quick support but maybe I didn't explain properly.
My goal is to obtain another column named **Count_Friday** in my data.frame that pinpoints the number of Friday in that month.
The variable **Count_Friday** increases in value every time finds **Flag_Friday** == 1 in a month.
When **Flag_new_month** == 1 then the variable **Count_Friday** resets to zero.
For example:

```
Dates       Month   Weekday         Flag_new_month  Flag_Friday Count_Friday
2014-01-15  1       Wednesday       0               0           0
2014-01-16  1       Thursday        0               0           0
2014-01-17  1       Friday          0               1           1
2014-01-18  1       Saturday        0               0           0
2014-01-19  1       Sunday          0               0           0
2014-01-20  1       Monday          0               0           0
2014-01-21  1       Tuesday         0               0           0
2014-01-22  1       Wednesday       0               0           0
2014-01-23  1       Thursday        0               0           0
2014-01-24  1       Friday          0               1           2
2014-01-25  1       Saturday        0               0           0
2014-01-26  1       Sunday          0               0           0
2014-01-27  1       Monday          0               0           0
2014-01-28  1       Tuesday         0               0           0
2014-01-29  1       Wednesday       0               0           0
2014-01-30  1       Thursday        0               0           0
2014-01-31  1       Friday          0               1           3
2014-02-01  2       Saturday        1               0           0
2014-02-02  2       Sunday          0               0           0
2014-02-03  2       Monday          0               0           0
2014-02-04  2       Tuesday         0               0           0
2014-02-05  2       Wednesday       0               0           0
2014-02-06  2       Thursday        0               0           0
2014-02-07  2       Friday          0               1           1
```

Thanks again for the support and hope to be more clear now.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're relatively close, but there are a couple of things that are off.  First, you're using `&&` instead of `&`.  Only the latter is vectorized (you use the former with `if/else`, and the latter with `ifelse`).  Additionally, the second condition doesn't work because `Flag_new_month` isn't always 1 on the Friday. I believe this does what you want:

```
ll$Count_Friday <- 
  with(ll, ifelse(Flag_Friday, ave(Flag_Friday, Month, FUN=cumsum), 0))
```

If you notice I don't use `Flag_new_month`, instead I use `ave` to break up the `Flag_Friday` column by month, and then within each month, do a cumulative sum of the Fridays.  The `ifelse` is just so that I only populate this cumulative sum value for Fridays (otherwise every day following a Friday up to the next Friday would have the same number as `Count_Friday`).

And here is the result.  Interestingly 2014 had 5 Fridays in the first month.

```
head(ll, 40)
#         Dates Month   Weekday Flag_new_month Flag_Friday Count_Friday
# 1  2014-01-01     1 Wednesday              1           0            0
# 2  2014-01-02     1  Thursday              0           0            0
# 3  2014-01-03     1    Friday              0           1            1
# 4  2014-01-04     1  Saturday              0           0            0
# 5  2014-01-05     1    Sunday              0           0            0
# 6  2014-01-06     1    Monday              0           0            0
# 7  2014-01-07     1   Tuesday              0           0            0
# 8  2014-01-08     1 Wednesday              0           0            0
# 9  2014-01-09     1  Thursday              0           0            0
# 10 2014-01-10     1    Friday              0           1            2
# 11 2014-01-11     1  Saturday              0           0            0
# 12 2014-01-12     1    Sunday              0           0            0
# 13 2014-01-13     1    Monday              0           0            0
# 14 2014-01-14     1   Tuesday              0           0            0
# 15 2014-01-15     1 Wednesday              0           0            0
# 16 2014-01-16     1  Thursday              0           0            0
# 17 2014-01-17     1    Friday              0           1            3
# 18 2014-01-18     1  Saturday              0           0            0
# 19 2014-01-19     1    Sunday              0           0            0
# 20 2014-01-20     1    Monday              0           0            0
# 21 2014-01-21     1   Tuesday              0           0            0
# 22 2014-01-22     1 Wednesday              0           0            0
# 23 2014-01-23     1  Thursday              0           0            0
# 24 2014-01-24     1    Friday              0           1            4
# 25 2014-01-25     1  Saturday              0           0            0
# 26 2014-01-26     1    Sunday              0           0            0
# 27 2014-01-27     1    Monday              0           0            0
# 28 2014-01-28     1   Tuesday              0           0            0
# 29 2014-01-29     1 Wednesday              0           0            0
# 30 2014-01-30     1  Thursday              0           0            0
# 31 2014-01-31     1    Friday              0           1            5
# 32 2014-02-01     2  Saturday              1           0            0
# 33 2014-02-02     2    Sunday              0           0            0
# 34 2014-02-03     2    Monday              0           0            0
# 35 2014-02-04     2   Tuesday              0           0            0
# 36 2014-02-05     2 Wednesday              0           0            0
# 37 2014-02-06     2  Thursday              0           0            0
# 38 2014-02-07     2    Friday              0           1            1
# 39 2014-02-08     2  Saturday              0           0            0
# 40 2014-02-09     2    Sunday              0           0            0
```

Here is how I made the data:

```
ll <- data.frame(Dates=seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), len=365, by="1 day"))
ll <- transform(
  ll, 
  Month=month(Dates), 
  Weekday=weekdays(Dates),
  Flag_new_month=diff(c(0, month(Dates))),
  Flag_Friday=as.integer(weekdays(Dates) == "Friday")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example the `plyr` package for this:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Dates           Month    Weekday     Flag_new_month  Flag_Friday
2014-01-30      1        Thursday    0               0  
2014-01-31      1        Friday      0               1  
2014-02-01      2        Saturday    1               0  
2014-02-07      2        Friday      1               1
2014-02-14      2        Friday      1               1')

head(df)
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Month), summarise,
      n_friday = sum(Flag_Friday))
```

Or just simply `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$Flag_Friday, df$Month, sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

A fully vectorized way of doing it:

```
> df<-data.frame(cbind(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0), c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)))
> colnames(df)<-c('Month', 'Friday')
> df
   Month Friday
1      0      1
2      0      0
3      0      1
4      1      0
5      0      1
6      0      0
7      1      1
8      0      0
9      0      1
10     0      0
> cumsum(df$Friday)-cummax(ifelse(df$Month==1, c(0,cumsum(df$Friday)), 0))
[1] 1 1 2 0 1 1 1 1 2 2
```